# How can we prove $\lim_ \limits{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$ without using La Hôpital's Rule?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

The limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$ can be proved using La Hôpital's Rule but is it possible to prove this limit using the definition of the limit?

Comment: @Surb Well, it was defined, in my book as $$e=\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t$$

Comment: @S.C.B.: If in one of your book is defined as the first limit, it's not an usual definition. But indeed, the second is the definition of $e$.

Comment: @Surb OK, that was a typo.

Comment: see here http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf i hope this will help you

Comment: What is your definition of $e$? If it is $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ there is nothing to prove, if it is $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ there is little to prove, if it is $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}$ there actually are some things to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Set $y=\frac{1}{x}$, and thus $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1+x)^{1/x}=\lim_{y\to +\infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y.$$

Comment: But then how will you prove $\lim \limits_{y\to +\infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y$?

Comment: @Razin: This is the definition of $e$ ! [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

Comment: @Surb: truth to be told, $e$ is usually defined as the limit of a sequence, not the the limit of a function. Still, there is little to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the limit exists and the value is some $l\in\mathbb{R}$, that is
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=l.$$
Consider the logarithm in both sides of the expression,
$$\log\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)=\log l.$$
This is equivalent to
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{1}{x}}\log(1+x)=\log l.$$
Now, since $\log(1) = 0$, we can write ${\frac{1}{x}}\log(1+x)$ as
$${\frac{1}{x}}\log(1+x) = {\frac{\log(1+x)-\log(1)}{x}},$$
and then, by the definition of the derivative, the limit on the left hand side is equal to $(log(x))'|_{x=1} = 1$. Thus,
$$1=\log l,$$
which means that the value $l$ is $e$.

Comment: I think you should clarify that the limit on the left hand side is equal to $1$ by the very definition of derivative, since one might think that l'Hopital is being used.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo You are right. Explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$A=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\implies \log(A)=\frac{1}{x}\log(1+x)$$ Now, remembering equivalents for small $x$ $$\log(1+x)\sim x$$ or Taylor series $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ you arrive to $$\log(A)\sim 1$$ or $$\log(A) =1-\frac{x}{2}+O\left(x^2\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define $e$ as that limit, you can do what follows:

$$\left( 1 + \frac1{x}\right)^x = \exp\left( x \ln \left(1 + \frac1{x}\right) \right) = \exp\left( x \cdot \left( \frac1{x} + O\left(\frac1{x} \right) \right) \right) = e \cdot \exp( O(1)) \to e$$